# ¿Cómo puedo usar código php tras una condición de php?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Buenas, estoy realizando un formulario combinando html, php y javascript. En dicho formulario recojo una serie de campos y con javascript debo asegurarme que se cumple una serie de condiones (email válido, nombre de usuario solo con caracteres, etc). He realizado una serie de funciones de javascript que realizan estas comprobaciones (el código se encuentra en un fichero externo) y si las cumplen, debo crear un fichero con el nombre recojido dentro del directorio de usuarios y meter una serie de datos. Mi problema reside en que no se como puedo usar esas funciones de javascript como condiciones para que me cree la carpeta y meta los correspondientes datos.

Este sería mi fichero de php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Registrarse</title>
    </head>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="cabecera">
                <header>
                    <div class = "titulo">
                        <h1>Organizacion DVD XIII</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buscador">
                        <input type="text" id="letras" placeholder="Buscar cualquier pelicula" maxlenght="500">
                        <input type="submit" id="boton" name="buscar" value = "Buscar">  
                        <select name="categorias" id="buscador_cat" >
                            <option value="Prueba1">Todas las categorias</option>
                            <option value="Prueba2">Prueba 2</option>
                            <option value="Prueba3">Prueba 3</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="links">
                         <a href="index.html">Indice</a>
                         <a href="login.html">Log In</a>
                     </div>
                </header>
            </div>
            
            <div class="navegacion">

                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="catalogo.html">Catalogo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Carrito</a></li>
                        <li><a href="historial.html">Historial</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        
            <?php
                if(!$_REQUEST){
            ?>

            <div class="loguearse"> 
                <article>
                    <form id="sigin" action = "signin.php" method="post">
                        <h2>Registrarse</h2>
                        <label><b>Nombre de usuario</b></label>
                        <input type="text" id ="nombre" placeholder="Introduzca usuario" name="name" required >
                        <div id="nombreErr"></div>
                        <label><b>Contrasenia</b></label>
                        <input type="password" id ="pass" placeholder="Introduzca contrasenia" name="psw" required >
                        <div id="passErr"></div>
                        <label><b>Confirma contrasenia</b></label>
                        <input type="password" id ="pass2" placeholder="Introduzca contrasenia" name="psw2" required >
                        <div id="pass2Err"></div>
                        <label><b>Email</b></label>
                        <input type="text" id ="email" placeholder="Introduzca email" name="email" required >
                        <div id="emailErr"></div>
                        <label><b>Tarjeta de credito</b></label>
                        <input type="text" id ="cash" placeholder="Introduzca tarjeta" name="creditcard" required ><br>
                        <div id="cashErr"></div>
                        <input type="submit" name="registrarse" value="Registrarse">
                    </form>
               </article>
            </div>
            <?php
                } else {
                    $user = $_REQUEST['name'];
                    $password = $_REQUEST['psw'];
                    $password2 = $_REQUEST['psw2'];
                    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
                    $tarjeta = $_REQUEST['creditcard'];
                    $directorio = "usuarios/$user";
                     
                    if(validarNombre() && validarPassword() &&validarPassword2() && validarEmail() && validarCash()){

                        if(!is_dir($directorio)){
                            mkdir($directorio, 0777, true);
                            chmod($directorio, 0777);
                            $iniciar = fopen($directorio.'/datos.dat', "w");
                            fwrite($iniciar, $user);
                            fwrite($iniciar, md5($password));
                            fwrite($iniciar, $email);
                            fwrite($iniciar, $tarjeta);
                            fwrite($iniciar, rand(0, 100));
                            fclose($iniciar);
                            $bd = fopen($directorio.'/historial.xml', "w");
                            fclose($bd);
                            
                            
                        } else {
                            
                        }
                    } else {
                        
                    }
                }

            ?>
            <script src="myJavaScript.js"></script>
            <div class="pie">
                <footer>
                    Copyright &copy; Organizacion DVD XIII
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
</html>
```

Y este el fichero de php:

```html
funcion validarNombre(){
    
    var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value; //Cogemos el valor de nombre
    var nombreErr = document.getElementById("nombreErr").value; //Cogemos la referencia al error del nombre
    var mensajeErr = ""; //Variable con el mensaje de error

    
    if(nombre.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)){
        nombreErr.innerHTML = ""; //innerHtml anyade codigo a lo que haya
        mensajeErr = "* Uso de carateres prohibidos.";
        nombreErr.innerHTML = mensajeErr;
        return false;
    } else if (nombre == ""){
        nombreErr.innerHTML = ""; //innerHtml anyade codigo a lo que haya
        mensajeErr = "* Nombre de usuario vacio.";
        nombreErr.innerHTML = mensajeErr;
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

funcion validarPassword(){
    
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value; //Cogemos el valor de password
    var passErr = document.getElementById("passErr").value; //Cogemos la referencia al error de password 
    var mensajeErr = ""; //Variable con el mensaje de error

    if(pass.lenght < 8 || pass.lenght < 25){
        passErr.innerHTML = ""; //innerHtml anyade codigo a lo que haya
        mensajeErr = "* La contrasenya debe encontrarse entre 8 y 25 carateres";
        passErr.innerHTML = mensajeErr;
        return false;
    } else if (!pass.match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/)){
        passErr.innerHTML = ""; //innerHtml anyade codigo a lo que haya
        mensajeErr = "* Uso de caracteres prohibidos.";
        passErr.innerHTML = mensajeErr;
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


funcion validarPassword2(){
    
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value; //Cogemos el valor de password
    var pass2 = document.getElementById("pass2").value; //Cogemos el valor de password2
    var pass2Err = document.getElementById("pass2Err").value; //Cogemos la referencia al error de password2 
    var mensajeErr = ""; //Variable con el mensaje de error

    if(pass != pass2){
        pass2Err.innerHTML = ""; //innerHtml anyade codigo a lo que haya
        mensajeErr = "* La contrasenya no coinciden.";
        pass2Err.innerHTML = mensajeErr;
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


funcion validarEmail(){
    
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value; //Cogemos el valor de email
    var emailErr = document.getElementById("emailErr").value; //Cogemos la referencia al error de email 
    var mensajeErr = ""; //Variable con el mensaje de error

    if(email.lenght == 0){
        emailErr.innerHTML = ""; //innerHtml anyade codigo a lo que haya
        mensajeErr = "* Campo vacio.";
        emailErr.innerHTML = mensajeErr;
        return false;
    } else if(!inputEmail.match(/^[^\s()<>@,;:\/]+@\w[\w\.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/i)){
        emailErr.innerHTML = ""; //innerHtml anyade codigo a lo que haya
        mensajeErr = "* Formato no valido.";
        emailErr.innerHTML = mensajeErr;
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


funcion validarCash(){
    
    var cash = document.getElementById("cash").value; //Cogemos el valor de cash
    var cashErr = document.getElementById("cashErr").value; //Cogemos la refernecia al error de cash
    var mensajeErr = ""; //Variable con el mensaje de error

    if(cash.lenght == 0){
        passErr.innerHTML = ""; //innerHtml anyade codigo a lo que haya
        mensajeErr = "* Campo vacio.";
        cashErr.innerHTML = mensajeErr;
        return false;
    } else if(!inputEmail.match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/)){
        cashErr.innerHTML = ""; //innerHtml anyade codigo a lo que haya
        mensajeErr = "* Formato no valido.";
        cashErr.innerHTML = mensajeErr;
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Además, si el nombre de usuario ya esta registrado debería de imprimir un mensaje de error al lado del campo de que recoge el nombre de usuario en el siguiente else:

```html
if(!is_dir($directorio)){
                            mkdir($directorio, 0777, true);
                            chmod($directorio, 0777);
                            $iniciar = fopen($directorio.'/datos.dat', "w");
                            fwrite($iniciar, $user);
                            fwrite($iniciar, md5($password));
                            fwrite($iniciar, $email);
                            fwrite($iniciar, $tarjeta);
                            fwrite($iniciar, rand(0, 100));
                            fclose($iniciar);
                            $bd = fopen($directorio.'/historial.xml', "w");
                            fclose($bd);
                           
                            
                        } else {
                            
                        }
```

He probado en usar echo "" para hacerlo, pero no funciona.

Gracias por la ayuda y un saludo!

Comment: El problema más grande que veo es que estás combinando llamadas de funciones de JS en código php lo cual simplemente no se puede hacer, para que tus funciones jalen deben ser enviadas al navegador para que este las ejecute, esto después de que la ejecución de código php terminó, tendrías que leer un poco de ajax y reorganizar tu código nuevamente para que puedas hacer lo que buscas, dado que la pregunta es muy amplia

Comment: El problema planteado no queda claro. Muchas cosas se aclararían si dijeras **dónde** quieres crear los ficheros (¿en el servidor, en el cliente?) Si es en el cliente, perfecto, Javascript sería suficiente, si es en el servidor, tendrías que enviar una petición al servidor vía Ajax, como ha comentado @Lixus. Para hacer ambas cosas, hay preguntas y ejemplos de sobra aquí mismo, en SOes.

Comment: Quiero crear los ficheros en el lado del servidor.